# mysql query select not in run too slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm trying to query SKUs not duplicated in product table like that:

```
SELECT entity_id, 
       sku 
FROM   catalog_product_entity 
WHERE  sku NOT IN (SELECT sku 
                   FROM   catalog_product_entity 
                   GROUP  BY sku 
                   HAVING Count(*) > 1)
```

But it runs very slow, even my PC is hanging on.
Anyone got a better solution for optimizing this query, please give me a help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the below query achieve the same thing?

```
SELECT entity_id, 
       sku 
FROM   catalog_product_entity 
GROUP  BY sku 
HAVING Count(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have index on `sku`.
Also try to use this query:

```
select MAX(entity_id),
       sku 
FROM catalog_product_entity 
GROUP BY sku
HAVING count(*)=1
```

Comment: thanks so much, that's it! it works to fast now! just add having before count(*)=1 it'll be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

you can  try to use this query

```
select 
entity_id, sku
from
catalog_product_entity
group by sku
having count(*) = 1
```